# I know there's "undo" in vim. What about a "redo"?

Tags: vim, undo

I'm used to do ctrl+z in other editors. Sometimes when you press ctrl+z too much, you can use ctrl+y and it redo the last action.

How do create this behavior in vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redo is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, in Vim.

You can find more information about Vim's commands at this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573/vim-tutorials).